# Unresolved compilation problem for parameterized java class method

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to check equlity of `num` object and `ob` object in `NumberFxn` Class.

It is showing this compilation error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method doubleValue() is undefined for the type NumberFxn<capture#4-of ?>

    at NumberFxn.absEqual(GenericsDemo.java:53)
    at GenericsDemo.main(GenericsDemo.java:74)
```

---

```
class NumberFxn<T extends Number>{
    T num;
    
    public NumberFxn(T num) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.num = num;
    }
    
    public boolean absEqual(NumberFxn<?> ob) {
        if(Math.abs(ob.doubleValue()) == Math.abs(num.doubleValue())) 
            return true;
        return false;
        
    }
}
```

---

Code of complete File:

```
class Container<T extends Number> {
    T value;
    
    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    void show() {
        System.out.println(value.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
    
}

class BigContainer<T,V>{
    T t;
    V v;
    public BigContainer() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public BigContainer(T t,V v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.t = t;
        this.v = v;
        
    }
    
    public void getStuff(T t,V v) {
        this.t = t;
        this.v = v;
    }
    
    
    public void printStuff() {
        System.out.println(t.getClass().getSimpleName()+"\t"+v.getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println(t+"\t"+v);
    }
}

class NumberFxn<T extends Number>{
    T num;
    
    public NumberFxn(T num) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.num = num;
    }
    
    public boolean absEqual(NumberFxn<?> ob) {
        if(Math.abs(ob.doubleValue()) == Math.abs(num.doubleValue())) 
            return true;
        return false;
        
    }
}


public class GenericsDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Container<Double> ob = new Container<>();       
        BigContainer<Double,String> obj = new BigContainer<>();
        ob.setValue(5.0);
        System.out.println(ob.getValue());
        ob.show();
        obj.getStuff(5.0, "Haritas");
        obj.printStuff();
        
        NumberFxn<Integer> a = new NumberFxn(6);
        NumberFxn<Double> b = new NumberFxn(-6.0);
        System.out.println("\n" );
        a.absEqual(b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NumberFxn<?> ob`
is a instance of `NumberFxn<? extends Number>`. This does **NOT** mean that `ob` is a sub class of `Number`.

It means only that the wrapped object(`T` type parameter object) inside the `ob` is a sub-class of `Number`.

Therefore you need to first fetch out that wrapped object(`num`)

```
ob.num.doubleValue()
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
class NumberFxn<T extends Number>{
    T num;
    
    public NumberFxn(T num) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.num = num;
    }
    
    public boolean absEqual(NumberFxn<?> ob) {
        if(Math.abs(ob.num.doubleValue()) == Math.abs(num.doubleValue())) 
            return true;
        return false;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: how does it work? It should have got value from its constructor.